# Take two values as an input in R list

Tags: r, list, lapply

If I have a list

```
sample <- list(a = c(1:5), b = c(11:15))
```

I would like to write a function like the following

```
res <- lapply(sample, function(x) { sample$a + sample$b * 5})
```

and the result would be just

```
[1] 56 62 68 74 80
```

I know this could be achieved by simple `sample$a + sample$b*5`, but I have complicated calculations that do not fall into it.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish here. You only give a function where you yourself admit that it can be rewritten easier, but have more complicated calculations that don't fall into this. So in what way do they not fall into this? Maybe it becomes more clear if you explain why you want to use `lapply` here. Edit: Also, the name `sample` was a bit confusing at first, as `sample` is a very commonly used function in R. You may want to switch to something like `lis`.

Comment: `sample$a + sample$b*5` doesn't yield th result you reported. Voting to close, as not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, I am careless

Comment: Aside from the result, what are you asking? Why can't you define a function `f` that takes two arguments and then just call `f(sample$a, sample$b)`? Please, give a clearer picture of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative using `do.call`

```
do.call(function(a,b) a + b*5, sample)
[1] 56 62 68 74 80
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using `mapply`

```
mapply(function(x,y) x+y*5, sample$a, sample$b)
```

Comment: Or its friendly wrapper `Map()`

Answer (score 1):

We could convert to `data.table` and do this

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sample)[, a+b*5]
#[1] 56 62 68 74 80
```

Answer (score 0):

`mapply()` and `do.call()` certainly work if you have to use lists for some reason. But, depending on your context, a `data.frame` could be a better data structure.

Using **dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(sample) %>%
  mutate(result = a + b * 5)
```

Or using base functions:

```
d <- as.data.frame(sample)
transform(d, result = a + b * 5)
```